# Null Pointer Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Ao rodar a aplicação, aparece este erro do Adapter:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference.
```

Pelo que consta, o erro está no método getView, e provavelmente nessa parte:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_notice, null);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Minha classe *Adapter*:

```
public class NoticeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Notice> itemList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public NoticeAdapter(List<Notice> itemList, Context ctx) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        if (itemList != null)
            return itemList.size();
        return 0;
    }

    public Notice getItem(int position) {
        if (itemList != null)
            return itemList.get(position);
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (itemList != null)
            return itemList.get(position).hashCode();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_notice, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view.setTag(holder);

            holder.tvId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.tvPtime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.publication_time);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvId.setText(itemList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.tvDesc.setText(itemList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.tvPtime.setText(itemList.get(position).getPublicationTime());

        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvId;
        TextView tvDesc;
        TextView tvPtime;
    }

    public List<Notice> getItemList() {
        return itemList;
    }

    public void setItemList(List<Notice> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Você tem certeza que o construtor está sendo chamado, e que a chamada `ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)` está retornando um objeto válido (e não `null`)? Não tenho experiência com Android, mas sua mensagem de erro sugere que é a própria `inflater` que está com valor nulo, de modo que eu investigaria se é isso mesmo que está acontecendo e, se for, qual pode ser a causa.

Comment: Era isto mesmo, @ramaral. Obrigado!!

Comment: Troque também `R.layout.list_notice` por `R.layout.item_layout` o *layout* aqui usado é o do item e não onde está a ListView.

Comment: @ramaral, será que eu poderia perguntar uma outra coisa sobre Fragment aqui, ou teria de abrir uma outra pergunta?

Comment: Depende da pergunta poder ser respondida por comentário ou não. Pergunte e depois vê-se.

Comment: É que a lista é carregada no Fragment com a seleção do ítem de menu da ActionBar. Contudo, quando eu clico numa tab diferente da que tem o Fragment com a lista, e retorno para a tab com a lista, a lista que estava anteriormente não é destruída. Ou seja, é feita uma nova requisição a API, retornam os dados normalmente e eles são adicionados a lista que já estava lá. Você sabe como eu posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Sei. Faça nove pergunta e coloque o código do *Fragment*.

Comment: @ramaral Agora estou curioso: cadê a resposta?! rsrs Pelo visto você e o AP andaram se falando em algum outro lugar, pois entre o meu 1º comentário e o seguinte, onde o AP te agradece, não tem nada. Afinal, o que realmente causou esse `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @mgibsonbr, o que causou a NullPointer, foi eu inflar o layout errado, como o ramaral respondeu acima :) kkkk

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu fiz um comentário a seguir ao seu que apaguei pois não estava 100% correcto. Nele eu dizia que o erro era devido à troca de layouts, o que não é verdade porque o erro indica que o `inflater` é nulo. Quando me apercebi disso já não foi possível editá-lo, decidi eliminá-lo e colocar outro.  Se verificar entre o meu poste e o do AP há 2s de diferença. Espero ter-me feito entender.